# xui swipe gesture not working on real device

Tags: javascript, cordova, xui

I am using `xui-swipe.js` for detecting swipe left and right gesture on a Phonegap application.

It is working fine on both android emulator and iPhone simulator. But when I installed this application to real device (Samsung Glaxy S3) swipe gesture detect the event only one time and after that nothing is detected; whether left or right.

Here is chunk of code used to detect the gesture (note that both `xui.js` and `xui-swipe.js` are included):

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function init ()
    {
        x$("#wrapper").swipe(function(e, data){
            var offset = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('offset'));
            switch(data.direction) {
                case 'right':
                    if (offset>0) {
                        sessionStorage.setItem('offset', offset-1);
                        document.location = "file.html";
                    }
                    //alert('right');
                    break;

                case 'left':
                    if (offset<10) {
                        sessionStorage.setItem('offset', offset+1);
                        document.location = "file.html";
                    }else {
                        document.location = "file-end.html";
                    }
                    //alert('left');
                    break;
            }
        }, {
            swipeCapture: true,
            longTapCapture: true,
            doubleTapCapture: true,
            simpleTapCapture: false
        });
    }

    var _timer=setInterval(function(){
        if(/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)){
            clearInterval(_timer)
            init() // call target function
        }
    }, 10);
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are case statement is wrong:

```
switch (data.type){
    case ('direction'):
      if (data.direction == 'left') {
        i--;
      } else {
        i++;
     }
```

You first need to check for the case 'direction', and then check if it is left or right.